# Firebase custom token authentication callback not called

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to authenticate with Digits (SMS/phone verification) and then in its callback on **success()** to call Firebase custom token authentication. All good, Digits works -> Firebase sends the authentication and actually loges the user in, but the callback of the Firebase **onComplete()** is not called. If I call **signInWithCustomToken()** directly without going through Digits, it works like it should, **onComplete()** it is called and all. What can the problem be?
 Here is what I have in my **onCreate()**:

```
    AuthConfig.Builder builder = new AuthConfig.Builder();
    builder.withAuthCallBack(new AuthCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            signInWithCustomToken();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
        }
    });

    authConfigDigits = builder.build();

    Button digitsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
    digitsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Digits.authenticate(authConfigDigits);
        }
    });
```

and then I have the custom token auth method **signInWithCustomToken()**  itself:

```
private void signInWithCustomToken() {

    String customToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2lkZW50aXR5dG9vbGtpdC5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9nb29nbGUuaWRlbnRpdHkuaWRlbnRpdHl0b29sa2l0LnYxLklkZW50aXR5VG9vbGtpdCIsImV4cCI6MTQ5Mzg0MDU5MiwiaWF0IjoxNDkzODM2OTkyLCJpc3MiOiJmaXJlYmFzZS1hZG1pbnNkay0xOXBqY0Btb3ZlY2VudHJhbC0zOGUzYS5pYW0uZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6ImZpcmViYXNlLWFkbWluc2RrLTE5cGpjQG1vdmVjZW50cmFsLTM4ZTNhLmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwidWlkIjoic29tZS11aWQifQ.QdyviQ8vMhpMF7VJP949PdjVBwqM4EbZGxJvhCQtsRloJdIc16FPBG_RrBp2wZivWC-z1TIx1yctdMVGsoDAk5ptp-HlNyp5n31DyfZriGgo8zbhWln4RGG4wGYb7hSxGpyvm4STOM9N7TBBKt4lCZFYdpHVbT2idhr0hipxKCC_Ubjhwbjsfxrj5h59GHSyAdjw_yigNBHEtvsUfdGfzwKn_EW5qm5OAA0icCiqjnvsvW5RkwWKo7kWxqZT87-BoHsf5JguFeLGs0Ow9lgxAS2mSuuvni5qiYdLZdOKhu204Ctsty1pyFYrAWwWdnSrTWJwdkBx9xPgsE5UlipkRQ";

    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Task is successfull");
                        openMainActivity();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Task failed");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for now by delaying the call of the **signInWithCustomToken()**.
I am not sure why it wasn't working, probably a race condition of some kind, but changing:

```
@Override
    public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
        signInWithCustomToken();
    }
```

with:

```
 @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //100ms delay
                    signInWithCustomToken();
                }
            }, 100);

        }
```

fixed the problem. If anyone can explain why, I'll greatly appreciate it.